# How to insert user specifc index while pusing item to the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert items in the array in a loop and want to index my own to each of item instead of default index offered by array itself so that i can get the index later can make a match with another object on that index.
I want to index the price array with the `index` in call back function, how can i do that?

```
var calculation = []; 
var priceArr = []; 
angular.forEach($scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation, function (value, index) {
  if ($scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index].IsApplied == true) {
    calculation.push($scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index]);
    priceArr.push($scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index].price);
  }
});
```

Here i want to mark index as `index` from the call back

```
priceArr.push($scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index].price);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value using the index instead of using `push`:

```
priceArr[index] = $scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index].price;
```

Comment: Isn't `$scope.ListCollection[i].lstCustomziation[index]` the same as `value` inside the function? :)

Comment: @Jack: Yes, good point. `priceArr[index] = value.price;` works the same. :) I'll leave the answer the same though, changing too much from the original code may confuse what the answer to the actual question is.